# Binary Set Calculator Function

Tags: c++, binary

So I've been working on a project for my C++ class, and we have to create a binary calculator. Yet the Professor says the functions should return an 8 bit binary set back. My issue is this

```
11111111 + 11111111 = 0111111110
```

Yet in the function we originally create this is the outcome

```
11111111 + 1111111 = 00000000
```

Which to me is incorrect. So I changed my function to this

**Decimal to Binary**

```
string DecToBin(int num)
{
  /*
        Purpose: Changing a Decimal to a Binary Set
        Pre: Valid positive integer
        Post: Returns the valid binary string
  */
  string bin = "";
  while (num >= 0)
  {
     bin += (num % 2 == 0 ? "0" : "1");
     if (num != 0)
         num /= 2;
     else break;
  }
 return bin;
}
```

Though here lies the issue again

```
01010101 + 10101010 = 011111111
```

But my function above returns

```
01010101 + 10101010 = 111111110
```

What would be the best possible function to create if one I NEED to return an 8 bit set or if like my said function above which returns the correct answer for some and wrong for the others which I need to figure out why that is in the first place.

**Binary to Decimal**

```
int BinToDec(string bin)
{
  /*
     Purpose: To generate a decimal integer from a string binary set
     Pre: Valid String binary set
     Post: Output the output decimal integer
  */
  int output = 0; //initialize output as 0
  int base2Start = 128;//base2 start at 128
  int len = bin.length();//get the string length
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)//iterate
   {
     if (bin[i] == '1')//if bin[i] in the array of string is a char 1
     {
         output = output + base2Start;//output gets + base2Start 
     }//end if condition
     base2Start = base2Start / 2;//divide base2Start after each iteration
   }//end for loop
    return output;//return the output
}
```

**Addition Function**

```
 int Addition(string st1, string st2)
  {    
    /*
       Purpose: Get's two valid Binary sets, then adds their decimal conversion, and returns the addition
       Pre: Need two strings that SHOULD be valid binary
       Post: Returns binary from decimal conversion
    */
    int first, second;

    if (ValidBin(st1))
    {
       first = BinToDec(st1);
    }
    else return 0;

    if (ValidBin(st2)){
       second = BinToDec(st2);
    }
    else return 0;

    add++;
    return first + second;
  }
```

Comment: where is the code where you do binary or operation? Also dont you think your bin should be reverse to get proper binary representation of decimal number?

Comment: Updated with more representation and other function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bin += (num % 2 == 0 ? "0" : "1");
```

Should be

```
bin = (num % 2 == 0 ? "0" : "1") + bin;
```

Since you each time you are adding the least significant bit of the `num` to string. So at the end, according to your code, you will have the least significant most left instead of most right.

**Edit:** In order to truncate the result to 8 bit width change the following line:

```
return first + second;
```

By the this one:

```
return (first + second) & 0xFF; // Same as (first + second) % 256
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question on should I use an 8 bit conversion function or should I stick to my guns here sending back a 10bit set? I don't fully understand binary so I can't really stand ground and argue with my professor on this subject.

Comment: If I understood correctly, your professor asked to return 8-bit outcome. So you need to truncate your result to 8 least significant bits. You didn't post here the code, which actually performs calculation, so I cannot point you exactly what should be changed in order to achieve this.

Comment: @EasyBB See my edited answer - you can use either `(first + second) & 255` or `(first + second) % 256` in order to truncate the result to 8 bit

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 string sumBinary (string s1, string s2);

 int main() 
 {

    cout << "output = "<<  sumBinary ("10","10");
 }

string sumBinary (string s1, string s2)
{

if (s1.empty())
    return s2;
if (s2.empty())
    return s1;

int len1 = s1.length() -1;
int len2 = s2.length() -1;

string s3;

s3 = len1 > len2 ? s1: s2;

int len3 = s3.length() -1;

bool carry = false;

while (len1>=0 || len2>=0) {

    int i1 = len1>=0? s1[len1--] - '0': 0;
    int i2 = len2>=0? s2[len2--] - '0': 0;

    // Check if any invalid character
    if (i1 <0 || i1>1 || i2<0 || i2>1)
        return "";

    // 3 bit sum            
    int sum = i1 ^ i2 ^ carry;

    // 3 bit carry
    carry = (i1 & carry) | (i2 & carry) | (i1 & i2);

    s3[len3--] = '0' + sum;

    }


if (carry)
    s3 = "1" + s3;

return s3;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?